# In QGIS how can I customize the label on a specific feature within a shapefile?

Tags: qgis, qgis-3

I have the following map.  I want the "North Loop Connector" on the east side of the map to have a different label.  Is it possible to associate metadata with a line string then include that in the label? Presently I am using a custom format `'North Loop Connector\n'||round($length)||'M'`.

The way I have been accomplishing this so far is to put each unique connector trail in a separate shape file, but that is going to make for  a lot of shape files and is difficult to manage.

I've attached a 2nd image that shows what I have now, with the layer information open.  Clicking either parts of the linestring brings up the same panel with no detail on the specific segment of the linestring.  **I need to be able to add data to the specific linestring segment, then display it in the expression for the layer.**

[image]

[image]

Comment: I may be missing something but if you add a field with the values being your labels, then label using field that no metadata is needed, nor manual writing.

Comment: Another option could be to use "rule-based" labelling in QGIS. You can set up conditions for specific labels / features and construct your label that way. All in one shapefile.

Comment: I think the main problem is that I don't know how to get the data I need (ie: the trail name) into that portion of the linestring or how to reference it in the expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by creating a custom field at the shapefile level, then setting a specific value for the field at the feature level.  To do this, enable `Select Feature By Single Click`

[image]

Once that is done, a toolbar button on the feature editing toolbar will appear.
Click that button, and then you can set a different value for your field.

[image]

End result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly then you just need to substitute the label text for the feature with the field that holds that data.
[image]

If not - perhaps add a bit more detail to the question relating to the features/attributes and what you need.

Comment: The expression you have is basically what I am doing now.  Applying data to the feature would not work,.  I need the data to live on a portion of the line string, is there a way to do that or no?  In your proposed solution, would still have to apply my same workaround of creating separate layers for each piece of trail I want to have a different label.  I updated my question above.  Asked another way, can I click on a portion of a linestring, and apply data to only that portion, then use that in my expression?

Comment: A label derived from a linestring feature's attributes will apply to all segments of the linestring - one solution would be to split the linestrings and use a new field to hold the data you want to display